# Find files containing one string but not the other

Tags: files, grep, find

I am in a folder with lots of `.txt` files, I would like to find all the files which contain `stringA` but don't contain `stringB` (they are not necessarily in the same line). Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As long as your filenames do not contain spaces, tabs, newline (assuming an unmodified `$IFS`) or wildcard characters and don't start with `-`, and if your `grep` supports the `-L` option, you can do it as follows:

```
$ cat file1
stringA
stringC
$ cat file2
stringA
stringB
$ grep -L stringB $(grep -l stringA file?)
file1
```

The `grep` executed in the subshell `$()`, will print all filenames which contain `stringA`. This filelist is input for the main `grep` command, which lists all files that do not contain `stringB`.

From `man grep`

> ```
>   -v, --invert-match
> ```

```
          Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v is specified by POSIX.)
```

> ```
>   -L, --files-without-match
> ```

```
          Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which no output would normally have been printed.  The scanning will stop on the first match.
```

> ```
>   -l, --files-with-matches
> ```

```
          Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which output would normally have been printed.  The scanning will stop on the first match.  (-l is specified by POSIX.)
```

Comment: Thank you... I have lots of files, your solution does give almost all the good results, but I see also several `grep: alias: No such file or directory`, do you know why?

Comment: Do you have a spaces in your filenames? Or aliases defined for grep?

Comment: Sometimes there are spaces in the filenames... What should I do to cover them?

Comment: @debai Sorry, I really don't want to change their filename, is there anything I can do on the level of the commands...

Comment: @SoftTimur grep -L stringB $(grep -l stringA `ls -l | tail -n+2 | awk '{print $NF}' | sed -e 's/\s/\\ /g'`

Comment: Sorry, how could i merge this with `grep -L stringB $(grep -l stringA file?)`?

Comment: @SoftTimur Please check my answer for proper formatting of the code.. :)

Comment: A whitespace-safe version should be something like `while read -rd $'\0' file; do grep -L 'stringB' "$file"; done < <(find . -type f -exec grep -Zl 'stringA' {} \;)`

Comment: @SoftTimur - Use his command and just precede it with: `IFS='\n' ;... ` where the `\n` is a literal newline. That will handle the spaces problem anyway.

Comment: useful to know if you use std::vector without (#)include <vector> `grep -L "<vector>" $(grep -rl std::vector *) | grep -v .so$ | grep -v .o$`

Comment: If the subshell returns no results, grep will wait forever since there is no output.
I suggest using `grep -lR 'wantedString' . | xargs -r grep -L 'non-wanted-string'`

The key being `-r` passed to xargs, which does not run the command if no arguments are available

Comment: @debal [piping `ls` like that is a bad idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425). `find` is the standard way

Answer (score 6):

With GNU tools:

```
grep -lZ stringA ./*.txt |
  xargs -r0 grep -L stringB
```

`-L`, `-Z`, `-r`, `-0` are GNU extensions sometimes but not always found in some other implementations.

Comment: For macOS: `brew install grep`, then use ggrep instead of grep. brew is a nonstandard command, it is "homebrew".

Comment: @artyom.razinov, actually as grep used to be GNU grep on FreeBSD (on which macos userland tools are based), it has kept a lot of the GNU grep API. IIRC it doesn't have `-Z` but it has the `--null` long-option equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

```
#run loop for each file in the directory
for i in `ls -l | tail -n+2 | awk '{print $NF}'` ; do
   #check if file contains "string B" 
   #if true then filename is not printed
   if [[ `egrep "string B" $i | wc -l` -eq 0 ]] ; then
      #check if file contains "string A"
      #if false then file name is not printed
      if [[ `egrep "string A" $i | wc -l` -gt 0 ]] ; then
         #file name is printed only if "string A" is present and "string B" is absent
         echo $i
      fi
   fi
done
```

---

After checking Bernhard's answer:

```
grep -Le "string B" $(grep -le "string A" `ls`)
```

If file name contains spaces:

```
grep -L stringB $(grep -l stringA `ls -l | tail -n+2 | awk '{print $NF}' | sed -e 's/\s/\\ /g'`
```

Comment: Maybe someone else can give a better solution to your space problem, but this is all I could think of at the moment. :) Cheers

Comment: People will complain that you are parsing `ls` :)

Comment: Thank you, but for the space problem, your commend still gives me errors like `grep: def.txt: No such file or directory` for filenames like `abc def.txt`.